# After watching the clip, they get/become/are manipulated

Tags: word-choice

Which one is the best choice? get/become/are

After watching the clip,

```
 1. she gets manipulated.
 2. she becomes manipulated.
 3. she is manipulated.
```

Because, watching the clip *makes* her manipulated, I think "get manipulated" is the best choice. However, "is manipulated" is way more popular. [(Source)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gets%20manipulated%2Cbecomes%20manipulated%2C%20is%20manipulated%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgets%20manipulated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecomes%20manipulated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20manipulated%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: you're changing too many things at one time there - 'she gets manipulate' is ungrammatical. 'She becomes manipulated' is a little strange, but 'becomes' and 'is' differs in a temporal sense.

Comment: Personally, I would change the sentence to "Watching the clip manipulated her to...", with the "manipulated" verb used right after the manipulator is mentioned.

Comment: Not enough information to provide an answer.  I think you have to answer *in your own mind* what the clip does to your character in concrete terms, at which point the choice of a general verb will come clear.

For all we can tell, this is a sentence about a princess contemplating a hair clip, or a beach party girl following a roach clip.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The question is renewed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403406/what-is-the-right-verb-for-manipulation-in-the-passive-sense

Comment: @GlobalCharm The question is renewed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403406/what-is-the-right-verb-for-manipulation-in-the-passive-sense

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider rephrasing with "brainwashed": After watching the clip, she became brainwashed with the idea that...

Or adding more detail to the object of manipulation, such as: After watching the clip, her thoughts about ... had been manipulated.

Of the three options you present, the second sounds preferable but still leaves some ambiguity about manipulation in the physical sense of moving someone (chiropractors manipulate the spine) or exerting some control/influence over thoughts etc.

Comment: The question is renewed here. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403406/what-is-the-right-verb-for-manipulation-in-the-passive-sense

Answer (score 0):

It should be : I was.

In this case.  But I can't explain really.

When in doubt ask yourself, "What sounds right?  What have I heard?"

I can say this much; you used it to convey a past thought, straightforward, not passive voice.
Also, were would be in question if it was hypothetical statement.  There are variations depending on many things in other statements.  This one is nice and simple.
That's my best for this.

Comment: The question is renewed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403406/what-is-the-right-verb-for-manipulation-in-the-passive-sense